# If $V$ is completely reducible and $End_{A}(V)$ is a division ring then $V$ is irreducible

Tags: modules

Since *V* is completely reducible we can write *V* as a direct sum of irreducible sub modules or a direct sum of 2 complement sub modules.
Can anyone give a hint on which way to write *V* and how can I make use of $End_{A}(V)$ as a division ring.

I think  writing $V = W \oplus U$ is better. Since *W* is any submodule.
I think I should choose a map from *V* to *W* and show that W is equal to {0} or *V*

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $V$ is not irreducible, i.e. $V=V_1\oplus V_2$.

Then $(Id_{V_1}\oplus0)\circ (0\oplus Id_{V_2})=0$. We deduce that $End_A(V)$ is not a division ring.

Comment: 0 is the zero function right?